# Yii2 BaseMailer test environment not saving or sending

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer, codeception

I'm running some unit tests, one of the tests checks that emails are generated and sent.

I have checked the docs, to force Yii to save the emails to a file rather than send I have configured `mailer` component as follows:

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => true
    ],
```

When running the tests I see the `Yii::info` message coming from the `BaseMailer send()` function.

> [yii\mail\BaseMailer::send] 'Sending email "Direct Debit Payment Notification" to "test@test.co.uk"'

However the email doesn't get saved anywhere, should be `runtime/mail`, it is not sent anywhere either.

I have tried to set `useFileTransport` at runtime using:

```
$mailer = Yii::$app->mailer;
$mailer->useFileTransport = true;
$mailer->composer...
```

But nothing changes, any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you saying the `@runtime/mail` has no emails saved ? its the default path for saving the emails in case `useFileTransport` is set. do you have sufficient rights on the directory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeception override your mailer settings ([[1]](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.4.5/src/Codeception/Lib/Connector/Yii2.php#L111) [[2]](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.4.5/src/Codeception/Lib/Connector/Yii2.php#L258-L287)) to use [custom mailer](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.4.5/src/Codeception/Lib/Connector/Yii2/TestMailer.php), which does not send or save anything. It makes sense - you don't want to send bunch of emails during testing.

You can use Codeception custom assertions or methods to test sent emails:

```
$I->seeEmailIsSent(3); // Test that three emails was sent

$messages = $I->grabSentEmails();
$I->assertEquals('admin@site,com', $messages[0]->getTo());
```

Comment: Yeah makes sense, they was never supposed to send. Just save them, so then I can do an assertion to check the correct amount of emails was generated

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Docs,`yii\mail\BaseMailer::useFileTransport` If enabled, this option enforces saving mail message data into the local files instead of regular sending. These files will be saved under `yii\mail\BaseMailer::fileTransportPath`, which is `@runtime/mail` by default.

So check your directory permissions if they are ok, you can change it to anyother directory that you know wont have permission issues by using `fileTransportPath`.

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
        // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
        // for the mailer to send real emails.
        'useFileTransport' => true,
        'fileTransportPath'=>'your/path',
    ],
```